# How to open the Visual Studio Editor Programmatically in a VSIX project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am working on a VSIX(Visual Studio Extension) project where I am fetching html text from a Service. I need to open the retrieved html text in the Visual Studio Editor. Any idea on how to achieve it or any sample code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the text to a .html file and then open it in the VS editor with `DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile(file);`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [AutoFindReplace](https://github.com/GregTrevellick/AutoFindReplace) extension which opens existing files in the editor window. You can download it from the [VS Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/02a85115-e23c-4e73-af09-957741c4f57d).