# How to resurface (activate) a specific document in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-sdk

I'm writing a small Visual Studio extension for VS2017 in C# and I'm trying something rather simple: If I press a button I want to resurface (make active) a specific document.

I have the `RunningDocumentInfo` from the `RunningDocumentTable` for this document, so I have its moniker and hierarchy and all that stuff. In the SDK docs I only found that the resurfacing can be done with `IVsUIShellOpenDocument.IsDocumentOpen` and the `IDO_ActivateIfOpen` flag. This sounds a bit inappropriate since I already know that the document is open for sure, but I'd go with it if it works. But how do I get a fitting instance that implements `IVsUIShellOpenDocument`? 
Or is there, by any chance, a simpler way that I just didn't find?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414944/how-to-open-the-visual-studio-editor-programmatically-in-a-vsix-project

Comment: Thx for the link, this actually worked:
```EnvDTE.DTE dte;
dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)Package.GetGlobalService( typeof( EnvDTE.DTE ) );
dte.ItemOperations.OpenFile( info.Moniker );```
It still feel strange to open a document you know is already open, so if there is a simpler way to just activate it I'd be more than happy, but as long as it does the trick I'm happy ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way I now accept as the solution:

```
foreach (Document doc in dte2.Documents)
{
    if (doc.FullName == Moniker)
    {
        doc.Activate();
        return;
    }
}
```

This traverses the currently opened documents until it finds the one I want to activate and activates it, just like I wanted :)